# Android(4.4+) WebView not showing iframe page content second time load

Tags: java, android, iframe, cookies, webview

i'm tring to show in webview page from local storage, it looks ok when page loaded first time, but when i remove webview and add it again it looks like on the picture (for 4.4+, on previous android versions just black screen):

[image]

webview adding progrommatcaly each time (using app context), switch off cache,cookies, and remove it in on destroy.

here is my code:

```
    mLayout = (LinearLayout)  view.findViewById(R.id.linear_main); 
    mWebView = new WebView(getActivity().getApplicationContext());  
    mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    mWebView.getSettings().setSaveFormData(false);  
    mWebView.setInitialScale(1); 
    mWebView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);  
    mWebView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);   
    mWebView.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(false);
    mWebView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE); 
    mWebView.getSettings().setDatabaseEnabled(false);
    mWebView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(false);
    mWebView.getSettings().setGeolocationEnabled(false);
    mWebView.getSettings().setSaveFormData(false);
    mWebView.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,  
            LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
    mWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
        mWebView.getSettings().setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs(true);
    }

    mWebView.getSettings().setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);
    mWebView.getSettings().setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON_DEMAND); 

    mLayout.addView(mWebView,0);  


    /// then display page by call
    public void display(String path){ 

    Map<String, String> noCacheHeaders = new HashMap<String, String>(2);
        noCacheHeaders.put("Pragma", "no-cache");
        noCacheHeaders.put("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
    mWebView.loadUrl(path, noCacheHeaders);

}

    /// after display destroy fragment  with the WebView 
@Override
public void onDestroy() { 
    super.onDestroy();
    CookieSyncManager.createInstance(getActivity().getApplicationContext());         
    CookieManager cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance();         
    cookieManager.removeAllCookie();
    mWebView.removeAllViews(); 
    mWebView.destroyDrawingCache();
    mWebView.clearDisappearingChildren();
    mWebView.clearFormData();
    mWebView.clearHistory();
    mWebView.clearCache(true);    
    mWebView.loadUrl("about:blank");
    mWebView.pauseTimers();

    mLayout.removeAllViews();

    mWebView.destroy(); 
    mWebView = null;
    getActivity().getApplicationContext().deleteDatabase("webview.db");
    getActivity().getApplicationContext().deleteDatabase("webviewCache.db");
}
```

could you please advice what else i need to try =)

Comment: are trying to load videos ?

Comment: no, one frame is google map, one for webpage, and 2 for images

Comment: wen add it again are you loading it with url ?

Comment: no, forgot to mention, i'm loading it from local file (every time), like file://<path>/page.html

Comment: getActivity().getApplicationContext() use activity context and check

Comment: just now tried, unfortunately the same result =( also i'm wondering about webview memory leak, one of advice was to use app context.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

looks that

```
mWebView.pauseTimers();
```

save data in some **static** variable... so, it doesen't matter that i've destroy webview and create new one, playing iframes were stopped. 
so, i've remove this line and it working now

be careful by using this flag

btw, guess it can related to memory leak issues.. but it's another story